# CSS: DIV with large font size (wrapping lines) is wider than necessary

Tags: html, css

Here is what I'd like to do:

I have a fixed-width container (black outline). In that container I'd like to show a number of flexible-width divs (red outline) each horizontally centered.

I do this by setting the outer div to `text-align:center` and then the inner div to `display:inline-block` and `text-align:left`.

It works in most cases, but when I increase the font size so that the text wraps across two lines, the inner div all of a sudden is wider than needed (see screenshot, excess space in yellow).

I'd like to have the inner div as small (horizontally) as possible so that it centers nicely.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txwbR/

[image]

*Edit:* If a CSS only solution is not possible, are there any suggestions for JavaScript solutions?

Comment: why do you have text-align:left? It should work without that. http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/txwbR/5/

Comment: @Danield I have `text-align:left` so that the text inside the div remains left aligned. In your demo it is centered. I only want the inner div centered, not its text content.

Comment: I think this is normal behaviour for inline-block elements - if it wraps it will then take 100% of the parent width

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most neat solution, but it works: use a line-break.

```
<div>some<br>content</div>
```

Comment: This is the only solution I see working without using js. In addition, if you have different sized text or change the size of the text in the box, you can set `<br>` to `display: none`. Just make sure you have a space before the `<br>`. http://jsfiddle.net/txwbR/62/

Comment: The problem with inserting <br> even with display:none is that the words will then always break. However, I have longer text and can't predict where it will/should break.